# Is there any way to convert string characters into integer?

Tags: c++

I have a question.

```
string test;
int sum = 0;

cout << "podaj liczbe; ";
cin >> test;
cout << "dlugosc: " << test.length() << endl;
for(int i = 0; i < test.length(); i++)
{
    cout << test[ i ] << endl;
}

cout << "suma" << sum << endl;
```

Lets say I will put a number `234` into string, program will show me `2, 3, 4` on screen and is there any way to create `int` with exactly value of `234`? And analogously if I put for example `555` number into string is there way to create `int` with `555` value?

Comment: [https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol)

Comment: Take a look at [std::stoi](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol)

Comment: why are your string characters alphapatical while u r talking about digit characters?

Comment: Love you baby:)

Comment: Its complicated, std::stoi helped, thanks all

Comment: @babidi Consider trying a google search before posting a question next time.